# Android to iPhone - clickable phone numbers in SMS messages

Tags: sms

Need a way to have clickable phone numbers from iPhone SMS's.

I started a new job with a company that uses iPhones, and we can send phone numbers that can just be tapped to be called. When that same SMS comes to my Android the phone number comes through as some download that I can't just click on to make the call back.

Does anyone know of a way that will allow for this "clickability" feature for the Android? (from an iPhone SMS sent to me). I looked at Handcent, and GoSMS already but they can't do it properly.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you possibly post a screenshot of what the SMS messages look like? Phone numbers should be clickable in android by default.